# Can anyone help me on how to sort div according to time? js

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I want to sort these html according to the date and time inside the div `.inner h6`. I tried many javascript and couldn't make it. I am new to js , please help

```
<div class="root-history">
    <div class="inner sc">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
        <h6>7/13/2021 8:10:20 PM</h6>
    </div>

 
    <div class="inner sc">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
        <h6>7/13/2021 8:11:55 PM</h6>
   </div>
 
    <div class="inner sc">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
        <h6>7/13/2021 8:10:12 PM</h6>
    </div>
 
    <div class="inner sc">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
        <h6>7/13/2021 8:10:43 PM</h6>
    </div>
 
    <div class="inner sc">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
        <h6>7/13/2021 8:10:34 PM</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

- We are sorting the children via `new Date(a.querySelector("h6").innerText) - new Date(b.querySelector("h6").innerText)`
- We are re-adding the children in corresponding order

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
[...root.querySelectorAll(".inner")]
  .sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.querySelector("h6").innerText) - new Date(b.querySelector("h6").innerText))).forEach(e => root.appendChild(e));
```

```html
<div class="root-history" id="root">
  <div class="inner sc">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
    <h6>7/13/2021 08:10:20 PM</h6>
  </div>


  <div class="inner sc">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
    <h6>7/13/2021 08:11:55 PM</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="inner sc">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
    <h6>7/13/2021 08:10:12 PM</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="inner sc">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
    <h6>7/13/2021 08:10:43 PM</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="inner sc">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle</span><br>
    <h6>7/13/2021 08:10:34 PM</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is actually not needed to do `innerHTML = ""`, as the DOM elements will just be moved by `appendChild`.